# Select all polygon on the google map

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to select all the polygon on the map without clicking on them, I want to send all polygon coordinates to the server and save them however I have to get all polygon path first then send them. I search a whole day for it, however, found nothing.
I create polygon with this code:

```
const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        drawingModes: ["polygon"]
      },
      polygonOptions: polyOptions,
      map: this.map
    });
```

Google map offers lots of event which can get polygon object however I want to select together

Comment: How are you creating the polygons? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you create each of the polygon objects for the map, store them to an array for future access

var polygons = [];

var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                        ...
                    });

polygons.push(polygon);

Comment: actually, users create polygons on the map I don't create them in this way and even though I could store them in the array I should also remove them when a user removes the polygon I want to know is a there better solution

Comment: The solution recommended by google is to keep a reference to them while users create them and whenever you want to get their coordinates or you want to remove them from map, use that reference.

Here is the link to google maps documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygon_remove

Answer (score 0):

```
var polygons = [];
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    polygons.push(polygon);
});
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.